# How to create a menu bar toggle in Mac OSX Lion?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, applescript

How would I go about creating a menu bar icon to toggle the microphone mute button?

Would I use AppleScript or Objective-C? What kind of project do I create in Xcode (if that's the IDE I should use). Thanks for any help or direction.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? There is a mute/unmute button on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
property toggled : 0 --0 means the mic is off, 1 means the mic is on
if toggled is 0 then
    set volume input volume 100
    set toggled to 1
else
    set volume input volume 0
    set toggled to 0
end if
```

Save this as a regular script file in the `Scripts` folder of the local `Library` folder.

If you have a little icon in your menubar that looks like a scroll (formerly known as the `Script Menu`), the script should appear somewhere in that menu. If you don't see the icon, run `AppleScript Utility` (located at `/Applications/AppleScript/AppleScript Utility`) and check the `Show Script Menu in menu bar` checkbox.

Now, all you have to do to run it is open up the Script Menu, find your script, and just click on it once. Questions? Ask. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way because we can get or set the output muted property of the volume directly...

```
set isMuted to output muted of (get volume settings)
if isMuted then
    set volume without output muted
else
    set volume with output muted
end if
```

As far as setting a menubar toggle, do as fireshadow52 suggested. Enable the applescript menu from the preferences in AppleScript Editor then place this applescript in the ~/Library/Scripts folder (create the folder if it doesn't exist).

***EDIT***: Sorry, I see you want the microphone muted not the volume! My mistake.